# How find this $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}$

Tags: number-theory

let $a_{i}\in [0,9],i=1,2,3,4,5$,and $a_{i}\in N,a_{1}\neq 0,a_{5}\neq 0$,such
$$5\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}=\overline{a_{5}a_{4}a_{3}a_{2}a_{1}}$$

Find the $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}$

my idea:since
$$5\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}=5a_{1}\times 10^4+5a_{2}\times 10^3+5a_{3}\times 10^2+5a_{2}\times 10+5a_{1}$$
$$\overline{a_{5}a_{4}a_{3}a_{2}a_{1}}=a_{5}\times 10^4+a_{4}\times 10^3+a_{3}\times 10^2+a_{2}\times 10+a_{1}$$
so we have
$$5a_{1}\le 9$$
$$a_{1}=1,a_{5}=5$$
then I can't

This problem is from book,and the book  can't  solution,I have consider sometimes,But I can't. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $a_1=5$, since multiples of $5$ can end only in $0$ or $5$, and $a_1=0$ is excluded. But then we'd have the product surpassing $5$ digits, since $5\cdot\overline{5abcd}\ge250000$. So there are no solutions to this problem.