# How find this value $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}=?$

Tags: number-theory

if the $a,b,c,d,e$ is  $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}$ a  permutation

and $a_{i}\in[0,9],a_{i}\in N$,such
$$\overline{abcde}=5\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}$$

Find the $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}$

where $a_{1},a\neq 0$

my idea:
$$\overline{abcde}=a\times 10^4+b\times 10^3+c\times 10^2+d\times 10+e$$
$$5\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}=5a_{1}\times 10^4+5a_{2}\times 10^3+5a_{3}\times 10^2+5a_{2}\times 10+5a_{5}$$
so we must $$a_{1}=1$$
and $e=0$ or $5$

Then  I can't

This problem is creat this :[How find this $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660301/how-find-this-overlinea-1a-2a-3a-4a-5?rq=1)

Thank you,maybe this have no solution too?

Comment: For six digits, there is $5\cdot 142857 = 714285$

Comment: @RossMillikan,Hello,But the problem is five digits,maybe is exsit? Thank you

Comment: The digits add up to a multiple of 9

Comment: Are the digits distinct?

Comment: @SandeepThilakan,can equal

Comment: Since the larger number is a multiple of 45, between 50000 and 100000, there are 1111 possible numbers, which can be done easily on Excel.  Checking the list takes a quarter hour or so, to see whether N and N/5 have the same digits.  I did that, and didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program in Python to check all possibilities. Assuming $a=1$, It puts all the digits in $\overline{abcde}$ in a list and all the digits in $5  \overline{abcde}$ in a list and checks to see if all the digits match. It returned no numbers, therefore there are no solutions.

Edit: Here is my ugly code:

```
for b in range(10):
    for c in range(10):
        for d in range(10):
            for e in range(10):
                new_num = str(50000 + 5000*b + 500*c + 50*d + 5*e)
                a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5 = new_num[0], new_num[1], new_num[2], new_num[3], new_num[4]
                a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5 = int(a_1), int(a_2), int(a_3), int(a_4), int(a_5)
                if sorted((1, b, c, d, e)) == sorted((a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)):
                    print(new_num)       

print("done")
```

Comment: I wonder if this holds for all words of length $n$ (discluding cyclic numbers)? Something like "a positive integer $m$ multiplied by another positive integer can only result in a positive integer with the same number of occurrences of each digit if $m$ is a cyclic number."

Comment: By another positive integer I assume you mean 2 through 9 right, because obviously 1 would work

Comment: Yea, or if you wanted to further generalize it, you can do $n \geq 2$ if one allows initial zero's to be included.

Answer (score -1):

Pick any $a_1$, $a_2$ etc so they are all either $0$ or $1$.
Now let
$$ a=5 a_1, b=5 a_2, c=5 a_3, d=5 a_4, e=5 a_5$$

By repeatedly taking the difference between the left and right side modulo $5$ and factoring out $5$ you get the above answer.

Example:
$$
\overline{50555} = 5 ~\cdot~\overline{10111}$$

Comment: Hello,I think you don't understand my problem.

Comment: sorry, you may be right! Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: The digits $a,b,c,d,e$ are the same as $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$, just in a different order.